# Update CSV files in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv

I use the following code into the CSV file info display give the data grid:

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Data.csv")

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)

    dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)),

                         New DataColumn(newline(1)),

                         New DataColumn(newline(2))})

    While (Not sr.EndOfStream)

        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)

        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

        newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1), newline(2)}

        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)

    End While

    dgView.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

I'm gonna change it using the code below, but the message was displayed:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim iRow As Integer = GridView1.GetSelectedRows(0)

    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Data.csv")

    lines(iRow) = lines(iRow).Replace("Value", "OK")

    IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Data.csv", lines)

End Sub
```

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Data.csv' because it is being used by another process.

And I can not save the changes.

How do I search the CSV files to a specified field and I edit it?

Comment: You've just gotta dispose your streamreader "sr" or open the file in a mode that does not prevent access to it

Comment: Instead of `Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader` use `Using sr As ...` it will close and dispose of the stream for you.  I should also mention that there are tools like CSVHelper which make working with CSVs simple